# Macro not working properly when assigned to Graphic icon in excel. But its working when running through VBA IDE

Tags: excel, vba

[image]I have macro which opens up the userform (which has textbox, listbox, clear button and confirm button). I assigned it to Graphic icon (Search icon). Whenever it is clicked - userform should show listbox with items and textbox with no text. But, here upon clicking the icon, by default I'm getting some values in textbox. This issue is not coming when I ran code from VBA IDE.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is your code?

Comment: is there a code in the listbox_change event?

Comment: Screenshots in which code is there is added here.
Thanks for the reply

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your `Listbox1_click` event. It looks like it's being triggered.